# JW player, on pause image overlay with hyperlink, how to?

Tags: jwplayer

i would like to know is this possible ?

what i am looking for is a banner or image should be overlayed at the cente of the player when a video is paused in jw player .

if so then i need a direction.

i am already doing this with a custom flash player by passing xml feed which have ads details to the player.

we are using feed like this

```
<ads><ad targeturl="linkhere"><image src="image-path" width="300" height="250"/></ad></ads>
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: I would recommend building a custom JW Player Plugin to do this. We have a SDK available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: thanks ethan, i am looking in to it.